# Geckodriver will not open

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am trying to launch FireFox with geckodriver and go to instagram.com. When I run my code, it launches FireFox but just sits at a blank tab and won't load instagram. I have the path to geckodriver set and I have selenium installed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


class InstagramBot:


    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)

        # "//a[@href'accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']"
        # "//input[@name='username']"
        # "//input[@name='password']"

monchaosIG = InstagramBot("username", "passoword")
monchaosIG.login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because incompatible app version, you need to install lasted [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much. That was dumb on my part. Easy fix :)

Comment: you're welcome. if it solved, please consider mark the answer as correct